# Connecting Azure Database Migration Service to self-hosted Integration Runtime in Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure, database-migration, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to migrate an on-premise SQL Server Database to an Azure SQL database using Azure Data Studio, using this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-managed-instance-online-ads#create-azure-database-migration-service

under **Create Azure Database Migration Service** **Step 5** (After successful creation of DMS, you'll be provided with details to set up integration runtime.)

In the wizard there is no option to configure the Integration Runtime
[image]

[image]

I have also tried adding the runtime to the Azure DMS in the portal but there are no buttons to add a new one:
[image]

Lastly I have tried adding the DMS to the integration runtime via the a DataFactory containing the IR:
[image]

This has all been done with sysadmin permissions.

I am trying to connect this DMS to an on-premise self hosted IR.

Any help would be appreciated